# Replacing whitespaces within list elements

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, whitespace

I have a list of tags:

```
>>> tags_list
['tag1', 'second tag', 'third longer tag']
```

How can I replace whitespaces within each element of the list with "+" ? I was trying to do this with regular expressions but each string remains unchanged:

```
for tag in tags_list:
    re.sub("\s+" , " ", tag)
```

What is wrong with my approach ?

EDIT:

Yes I forgot to mention, that between the words in each tag we can have multiple whitespaces as well as tags can begin or end with whitespaces, since they're parsed from a comma separated string with split(",") : ("First tag, second tag, third  tag"). Sorry for not being precise enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[re.sub()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) returns a new string, it does not modify its parameter in-place.

You probably want:

```
tags_list = [re.sub(r"\s+", "+", tag) for tag in tags_list]
```

Also, don't forget the `r` before the regex or you'll have to double all the backslashes inside (i.e. the regex you posted won't work).

**EDIT:** I assume `replace whitespaces within each element of the list with "+"` means collapsing all consecutive whitespace into a single `+`character. If not, use `r"\s"` instead of `r"\s+"`.

Answer (score 2):

What you were doing is not replacing spaces with `+`, you were replacing multiple whitespace characters with a single space, on top of that you were throwing results out. Here is what you need:

```
>>> tags = ['tag1', 'second tag', 'third longer tag']
>>> [re.sub(r'\s+', '+', i.strip()) for i in tags]
['tag1', 'second+tag', 'third+longer+tag']
>>> tags
['tag1', 'second tag', 'third longer tag']
```

Comment: As @Axidos pointed out in a comment to my deleted answer, this does not work for consecutive spaces or tabs or newlines.

Comment: @Space: OP clearly mis-represents his actual task. If you look at his example, he doesn't deal with consecutive white spaces at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> tags = ['tag1', 'second tag', 'third longer tag']
>>> [ '+'.join(i.split()) for i in tags ]
['tag1', 'second+tag', 'third+longer+tag']
```